# Присвоение итераторов одного контейнера

Tags: c++, итераторы

Подскажите, есть возможность в С++ присвоить итератор одного контейнера итератору другого такого же?
Я знаю про метод сравнивания с помощью std::distance(), однаком у меня задача иная возникла.

Скажем, есть два вектора и я хочу перебрать один, в определённый момент взять итератор и произвести с элеменом (под этим итератором) действия как в первом, так и во втором массиве. Понимаю, что просто так это не сделать, но вдруг есть методы...

Вот для наглядности, как это сейчас:

```
vector v1<int>, v2<int>;

auto j = v2->begin();
for (auto i = v1->begin(); i < v1->end(); i++, j++)
    if (temp_int == *i)
    {
        v1->erase(i);
        v2->erase(j);
        break;
    }
```

Ну и вопрос, на всякий случай, если вдруг такой метод приведения итераторов найдётся, на сколько он рационален, может вариант выше *внезапно* будет быстрее.

Comment: присвоить  итератор одного контейнера итератору другого контейнера невозможно. И у вас v1, v2 являются обьектами, а не итераторами или указательями, так что  не v2->begin();, а  v2.begin();...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дли итераторов с произвольным доступом можно использовать смещения - `it+delta`, что-то такое. Но абсолютно тот же эффект даст

```
j = v2->begin();
advance(j,distance(v1->begin(),i);
```

при этом этот способ применим к любым итераторам. Но поскольку для итераторов не RandomAccess все равно будет выполняться набор `++`, то ваш способ с одновременным увеличением двух итераторов получается и самым эффективным, и самым обобщенным.

Мне кажется, что `++` для итератора - не такая уж затратная операция, чтоб ваш способ был не эффективным даже для векторов.

И еще - надо помнить, что для ассоциативных контейнеров могут быть свои нюансы из-за сортированности. В том смысле, что вы должны точно понимать, что делаете.

Answer (score 2):

Так как итераторы в векторе позволяют произвольный доступ можно получить итератор по индексу, а индекс можно получить вычтя два итератора:

```
auto const item_index{p_v1_item - v1.begin()};
auto const p_v2_item{v2.begin() + item_index};
v1->erase(p_v1_item);
v2->erase(p_v2_item);
```

Comment: Вы просто написали частный случай функции  std::distance  для итераторов произвольного доступа

Comment: Это же только для итераторов с произвольным доступом.

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать самому класс или функцию, где будет выполняться желаемое вам действие. Но чтобы не воспользоваться услугами функции std::distance, ее придется написать самому, а я не вижу в этом смысла(если только не для учебного процесса).
Я приведу пример(может не совсем удачный или не совсем то, что вы хотели), с помощью которого может у вас возникнуть идея для  полноценного решения своей задачи:

```
template < class C >
class G {
    C c;
    std::function< typename C::iterator(C& cont) > f;    
public:
    G(C& cont, std::function<typename C::iterator(C&) > fnc) : c(cont), f(fnc) {}
    typename C::iterator
    operator ()(C& cont) {
        size_t n = std::distance(std::begin(c), f(c));
        auto It = std::begin(cont);
        while(n-- && It != std::end(cont)) ++It;
        return It;
    }
};
```

обькт класса конструируется контейнером и указателем на некоторую функцию, возвращающую итератор на этот контейнер. Напишем для примера функцию:

```
// некая функцию, возвращающая итератор контейнера
template<int temp_int>
vector<int>::iterator foo(vector<int>& v)
{
    return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), temp_int);
}
```

и наконец пример программы:

```
vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3}, v2{12, 13, 14};
G<vector<int> >  gen(v1, foo<3>); //находим 3 в первом контейнере
auto It = gen(v2);
string message = "\nout of range\n";
// выводим соответствующий  элемент второго
if (It == v2.end())
    cerr << message;
else
    cout << *It;
```